# Can I create a custom expression without using the where clause?

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, connect-by, nhibernate-criteria

While I have already solved this issue in a previous question using a native query. I am now wondering if it is possible to create a custom expression that is usable in a Criteria without using the where clause? The reason I don't want the where clause is because Oracle's `connect by ... start with ...` ([here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html)) statement. I followed [this](http://xlib.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/integrating-freetext-search-in-nhibernate-detached-criteria/) page to get my started. However, this will generate code like `select * from foo where connect by start with`...

Here is what I am using. Looking at what gets generated I can say that it is generating the correct statement minus the where clause.

```
public class StartWithConnectByCriteria : AbstractCriterion
{
    public StartWithConnectByCriteria(string parentName, string parentValue, string childName)
    {
        ParentName = parentName;
        ParentValue = parentValue;
        ChildName = childName;
    }

    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public string ParentValue { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public IProjection P { get; set; }

    public override IProjection[] GetProjections()
    {
        if(P != null)
        {
            return new IProjection[] {P};
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override TypedValue[] GetTypedValues(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    {
        return
            CriterionUtil.GetTypedValues(criteriaQuery, criteria, P, ParentName, ParentValue.ToString());
    }

    public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery,
                                          IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
    {
        var sqlBuilder = new SqlStringBuilder();
        SqlString[] parentColumnNames = CriterionUtil.GetColumnNames(ParentName,
                                                               P, criteriaQuery,
                                                               criteria, enabledFilters);
        SqlString parentColumnName = parentColumnNames[0];

        SqlString[] childColumnNames = CriterionUtil.GetColumnNames(ChildName,
                                                   P, criteriaQuery,
                                                   criteria, enabledFilters);
        SqlString childColumnName = childColumnNames[0];

        criteriaQuery.AddUsedTypedValues(GetTypedValues(criteria, criteriaQuery));
        sqlBuilder
            .Add("start with " + parentColumnName + " = '" + ParentValue + "'")
            .Add(" connect by prior " + childColumnName + " = " + parentColumnName);

        return sqlBuilder.ToSqlString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I am using it like this.

```
StartWithConnectByCriteria criterion = 
    new StartWithConnectByCriteria(
        "parent", 
        "parent_value", 
        "child");

DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.For<NormalUpstream>("nu")
    .Add(criterion);
```

I have a feeling it has to do with the `.Add()` from the DetachedCriteria but not 100% sure. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find much documentation about creating a custom expression.

Edit: Now that I think about it looks like I'm barking up the wrong tree. While this isn't crucial (I already have a decent implementation). I'm still interested in seeing how I can further customize NHibernate.

Edit 2: Since out of the box NHibernate doesn't support Oracle's proprietary function, `start with ... connect by`. I'm trying to learn more about extending NHibernate by adding native support for it. I'm aware I can register those function with a custom dialect. But I'm wondering if it's possible to implement it as a Criteria so I can use it with my other criteria queries. The code I posted works fine and correctly creates valid SQL but when I add StartWithConnectByCriteria to my criteria, NHibernate will issues a query such as `select this_.id from table where start with ... connect by`. Which is an invalid query because that clause does not belong with the where.

This is the query I'd expect for NHibernate to generate.

```
select
    random_column
from
    table
start with parent_id = 'parent_node_id'
connect by prior child_up_id = parent_id
```

Notice how there is no `where` clause in this query. However, `start with ... connect by` could still be used with a `where clause`. You can read more about how those keywords work [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the existing NHibernate syntax allows for this, but there is an ANSI standard syntax for hierarchical queries which may prove useful. I believe it only works in 11R2 and above, however, so I'm not sure if it is useful for you. See [Recursive Subquery Refactoring](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10002.htm#BABCDJDB) for more information.

Comment: I don't think the Criteria API supports `WITH`. I might be able to get away with us using HQL or a native SQL query. Thank you.